# extracting data from columns in a text file using python

Tags: python, csv, file, text, multiple-columns

I am new to python file data processing. I have the following text file having the report of a new college campus. I want to extract the data from the column "colleges" and for "book_IDs_1" for block_ABC_top which is 23. I also want to know if there is any more occurrence of block_ABC_top in the colleges column and find the value for the book IDs_1 column.
Is it possible in a text file? or il have to change it to csv? How do i write a code for this data processing? Kindly help me!!

```
Copyright 1986-2019, Inc. All Rights Reserved.

Design Information
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Version : (lin64) Build 2729669 Thu Dec  5 04:48:12 MST 2019
| Date         : Wed Aug 26 00:46:08 2020
| Host         : running 64-bit Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.8 
| Command      : college report
| Design       : college
| Device       : laptop
| Design State : in construction
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Table of Contents
-----------------
1. Information by Hierarchy

1. Information by Hierarchy
---------------------------
+----------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------+------------+------------+---------+------+-----+
|                   colleges                   |                   Module                   | Total mems | book IDs_1 | canteen | BUS  | UPS | 
+----------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------+------------+------------+---------+------+-----+
| block_ABC_top                                |                                      (top) |         44 |         23 |       8 |    8 |   8 |   
|    (block_ABC_top_0)                         |                            block_ABC_top_0 |          5 |          5 |       5 |    2 |   9 |       
+----------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------+------------+------------+---------+------+-----+
```

I have a data List which has data of the colleges such as block_ABC_top, block_ABC_top_1,block_ABC_top, block_ABC_top_1...Here is my code below
The problem i face is..it only takes the data for data[0]..but i have data[0] and data[2] having the same college and i expect the check to happen twice.

```
with open ("utility.txt", 'r') as f1:
            
            for line in f1:
                if data[x] in line:
                    line_values = line.split('|') 

                    if (int(line_values[4]) == 23 or int(line_values[7]) == 8):
                        filecheck = fullpath + "/" + filenames[x]
                        print filecheck

                        #print "check file "+ filenames[x]
                    x = x + 1

            f1.close()
```

Comment: Is there a specific issue? Have you tried anything, done any research? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: @AMC...yeah..i tried searching the data block_ABC_top in the file and extracting that line...but how do i specifically extract the data from Block id column from this line?

Comment: Please share the code you have so far, then, as well as the specific problem you encountered.

Comment: @AMC..edited with code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To extract Book id column data, use code below

```
with open('report.txt') as f:
  for line in f:
    if 'block_ABC_top' in line:
      line_values = line.split('|')
      print(line_values[4]) # PRINTS 23 AND 5
```

Answer (score 1):

```
print [x.split(' ')[0] for x in open(file).readlines()]  #colleges column
print [x.split(' ')[3] for x in open(file).readlines()]  #book_IDs_1 column
```

Try running these.

Comment: @yansh...i ran this...but i specifically want data for block_ABC_top  from the book IDs_1 column...not seperately extract the data..also the input file has some text details on top of the table...:(

Answer (score 1):

Instead of going with the exact position of reach field, a better way would be to use the `split()` function, since you have your fields separated by a `|` symbol. You can loop thru the lines of the file and handle them accordingly.

```
for loop...:
    line_values = line.split("|")

print(line_values[0]) # block_ABC_top
```